# Recursively grep data from certain files in the directory and return values to file

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am making a simple shell script which will minimize the time I spend in searching all directories under a parent directory and grep some things inside some files. Here's my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
MainDir=/var/opt/database/1227-1239/

cd "$MainDir"

for dir in $(ls); do

grep -i "STAGE,te_start_seq Starting" "$dir"/his_file | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out

if [ -f "$dir"/sysconfig.out];
then
    grep -A 1 "Drive Model" "$dir"/sysconfig.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
else
    grep -m 1 "Physical memory size" "$dir"/node0/setupsys.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
fi

done
```

The script is supposed to grep the string `STAGE,te_start_seq Starting` under the file `his_file` then dump it `sst-logs.out` which it does. My problem though is the part in the `if` statement. The script should check the current directory for `sysconfig.out`, grep `drive model` and dump it to `sst-logs.out` if it exists, otherwise, change directory to `node0` then grep `physical memory size` from `setupsys.out` and dump it to `sst-logs.out`. My problem is, it seems the `if then else` statement seems not to work as it doesn`t dump any data at all but if i execute grep manually, i do have data.

What is wrong with my shell script? Is there any more efficient way in doing this?

Comment: use shell debugging to see what is being executed with what values for the variables. `set -vx`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you say "change directory to node0 then grep" you're not changing dirs here you're just using a different path.  Do you really want to change directories?  Is "$dir/node0/" or is it outside of the directory "$dir"?

Second, does /var/opt/database/1227-1239/ have any files with spaces?
Can you show the output of ls?

I wouldn't use 'for dir in $(ls); do'

You'll start to run into a lot of pitfalls when you [attempt to parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
for dir in * ; do 
 if [[ -d "$dir" ]] ; then
  grep -i "STAGE,te_start_seq Starting" "$dir"/his_file | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
  if [ -f "$dir"/sysconfig.out]; then
   grep -A 1 "Drive Model" "$dir"/sysconfig.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
  else
   grep -m 1 "Physical memory size" "$dir"/node0/setupsys.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
  fi
 if
done
```

You can also use find -maxdepth if you got it, otherwise it turns into a .. -prune -o ..

My only guess is that $(ls) has some files with bad characters or spaces so when you manually process the files everything works because you're escaping these characters?

Comment: Hi Derek. 1. Yes, I really need to change directory if sysconfig.out does not exist. 2. No spaces are in any file names / folders. Basically, I am fetching the ram size of the units which exists on sysconfig.out or setupsys.out

Comment: Then I would cd to a different directory in the else block of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like

```
find . -name "*" -print | xargs grep -i <text>
```

To search `text` in all files under current directory

Answer (score 0):

have you heard of grep's recursive option?

```
grep <text> -R .
```